# Gray overlay after login

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, monitor

After recent update and restart my screen is overlaid with semi-transparent gray.

I've got no clue how to solve it, only thing that sort of works is changing monitors arrangement in settings, so that only the laptop's screen is gray, That works for multi-screen setup (well, not really, my laptop's screen is unusable), but doesn't solve it for normal, laptop-only use.

Below screenshots to better understand it.

Does anyone have any ideas? Googling doesn't really help

**UPDATE:**
It seems to be user-related. I've created a new user and it looks all right.

**UPDATE 2:**
Setting brightness with xrandr (`$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 1`) does work, but it does not have any influence on the overlay.

**UPDATE 3** Maybe good to mention that this overlay does not affect the cursor. It stays at normal brightness at all times.

Gray overlay:
[image: Gray overlay]

Rearranging laptop screen moves the overlay:
[image: Rearranging laptop screen moves the overlay]

My current setup being a "solution":
[image: My current setup being a "solution"]

Comment: If you type `xset` do you see anything relating to Screensaver or DPMS? The grey looks similar to the power save dimming effect on older Asus laptops.

Comment: Yes, there's screen-saver control, tried most of options, does not seem to have any influence on the issue. DPMS options also do not help. Thanks for tips, though! My laptop is a dell precision 5510.